# How to make metatags output proper images urls

Tags: meta-tags

I'm tring to create set of open graph tags for better sharing of my page. Unfortunatelly I cannot make Metatags output proper path to images attached to nodes. I have node with field_promoted_image. In metatags configuration I put:
[node:field-promoted-image] 
[node:field-promoted-image:file:url]
[node:field-promoted-image:file]

but all I get is field name or file name but without proper path.

Comment: [node:field-promoted-image:file:url] is the right token for image field. You will have to clear cache in order for your token change to take effect. Also, make sure that your OG images are stored in public files folder.

Answer (score -1):

if you get the file name with [node:field-promoted-image:file:url] just put the right path bevore the token. yoursite.de/thepathtoimage[node:field-promoted-image:file:url]or maybe you can put the base path token before it